# QJsonObject ::insert compared to direct assignment to QJsonValueRef?

Tags: c++, json, qt

I am using JSON in Qt for quite a time now and I always did it the way it is shown in the [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-json-savegame-example.html). However, I would like to know if there is actually a difference between this direct assignment to the *QJsonValueRef* compared to using `QJsonObject::insert` when adding items to [QJsonObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html), i.e. are these lines:

- `json["name"] = mName;`
- `json.insert("name", mName);`

different by any means or it is just a matter of a coding style?

Comment: Well if it's anything like `std::map` the call to `insert` won't replace the value of an existing key-value pair where using the index operator does.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious Well, the documentation of QJsonObject::insert (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html#insert) says it will: "If there is already an item with the key key, then that item's value is replaced with value."

Comment: And thanks for the fast response, of course!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually, it is different. The `operator[](const QString &key)` returns a reference to the JSON `value` (i.e. `key` is not included) pointed by the `key`, while `insert` method will add/replace the value then return an `iterator` to the value (i.e. we can access the `key` and `value` through the iterator). Thus, using `operator[]` you only gained an access (reference) to a specific value pointed by `key`, and when using `insert`, you got an `iterator` which can be used to access the element (key,value) itself and previous/next (if any) element in the JSON object.

Technically, according to [the source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/json/qjsonobject.cpp.html#447), in the `operator[](const QString &key)`, first it will search a value pointed by `key` and if exists, *the reference* will be returned. If the value does not exists `insert` will be called with *an empty QJSonValue()* as the second argument, then a reference to this new value will be returned. Since your call to the `operator[]` is followed by value modification, the effect of both operations in question will be the same, i.e. it assign `mValue` to the element having key `"name"`.

Comment: Now I understand the difference. This insight shed some light on how does it work behind the scenes and at least for me is very helpful. Thank you!